# Meteor - Form not being inserted into collection when submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am attempting to store information that is put into this form with meteor:

```
<form class="form-group" id="lost_form">
      <label for="item_name">Type</label>
      <input id="item_name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="What is the item? Ex: Water bottle" required/>

      <label for="item_brand">Brand</label>
      <input id="item_brand" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="What brand is the item? Ex: Nalgene" required/>

      <label for="item_desc">Description</label>
      <input id="item_desc" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Describe the item. Ex: Green, name on bottom" required/>

      <label for="item_loc">Location</label>
      <input id="item_loc" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Where did you have it last? Ex: Main common room"/>

      <label for="item_date">Date Missing</label>
      <input id="item_date" class="form-control" type="date"/>

      <br>
      <input id="submit_lost_form" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
```

The JS I am using to put it into a collection is below:

```
LostItems = new Meteor.Collection('lostitems');

Meteor.methods({
  'insertItem': function(iname, ibrand, idesc, iloc, idate){

    LostItems.insert({
      user: Meteor.user(),
      name: iname,
      brand: ibrand,
      description: idesc,
      location: iloc,
      date: idate
    })
  }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.lost_form.events({
    'submit form': function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var itemName = event.target.item_name.value;
      var itemBrand = event.target.item_brand.value;
      var itemDesc = event.target.item_desc.value;
      var itemLoc = event.target.item_loc.value;
      var itemDate = event.target.item_date.value;
      Meteor.call('insertItem', itemName, itemBrand, itemDesc, itemLoc, itemDate);
    }
  });
}
```

But whenever I submit the form, nothing happens. There are no errors in the developer console, or on the meteor console, and when I do `LostItems.find().fetch()` there is nothing there.

I am new to meteor so this is probably a really dumb question, but I appreciate any help!

Comment: this works - and is just like your code excluding the user field. http://meteorpad.com/pad/JkxBLRq8XLJTpxvnc/Leaderboard
If the user field was the problem I don't think it would fail silently though, so I think your issue may be elsewhere.

Comment: In your example it's not obvious how your template is named. Your form has an id of `lost_form` and you set your events on `Template.lost_form`. Did you name your template also `lost_form`? Then it should work as @JeremyK stated. Otherwise it's clear why it's not working.

Comment: @Valentin my template is named `lost_form` as well. Should the form have a name attribute instead of ID? would that make a difference?

Comment: Nope … yo don't even need an ID since you are not querying it.
Does the page reload when submitting the form? 
Also you could check the server log output.

Comment: @JeremyK the only error being raised is that I have two templates named `lost` but I cant find the duplicate. Would that do it?

Comment: @Valentin the page doesn't reload. The form also isn't cleared. Nothing happens at all. Very strange

Comment: @JeremyK I added the `lost count` to my page to test if it was storing the form, and when I click submit, the 0 turns to a 1 for a split second and then right back again.

Comment: Look at Dean Brettle's answer below. It allows you to remove the auto publish package, and explains why you see lost_count briefly show 1 before reverting to 0. This is called Latency Compression. discovermeteor.com/blog/latency-compensation

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `Meteor.userId()` instead of `Meteor.user()` in your call to `insert()`. Without the `autopublish` package, the doc returned by `Meteor.user()` can be different on the client than it is on the server (for security reasons). That would mean that the client-side insert into your mini-mongodb and the server-side insert into the real mongodb could conflict with each other. I would expect the client-side insert to be ignored after the result of the server-side insert propagates back to the client. I'm not sure why it isn't being replaced by the server-side insert though. What does `LostItems.find().fetch()` return when you run it on the server (e.g. in `meteor shell`)?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue by adding `insecure`, `yogiben:autoform-tags` and `autopublish` to my package list. I think `autopublish` is the one that made the difference. I am sure there is a better way to do this and that this probably has some security flaws to it, but this is not a big project and it isn't storing sensitive data, so this will work for now.

Comment: Look at Dean Brettle's answer below. It allows you to remove the auto publish package, and explains why you see lost_count briefly show 1 before reverting to 0.  This is called Latency Compression. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/latency-compensation/